# Send recorder data in chunks to an API

Tags: javascript, blob

I want to have a recorder running on a website where every few seconds a post request is send to an api call to transcribe it.

However, the first time it works, but after that it will give this error:

"Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': 'The audio file could not be decoded or its format is not supported.', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}"

I tried to give it every time an temporary file name, but that did not work. I tried making the interval longer or shorter.

```
let mediaRecorder;
let audioChunks = [];
let sendInterval;

document.getElementById('recordBtn').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state === "recording") {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        clearInterval(sendInterval); // Clear the interval when stopping
        document.getElementById('recordBtn').textContent = 'Start Recording';
    } else {
        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                if (event.data.size > 0) {
                    audioChunks.push(event.data);
                    console.log('Chunk received:', event.data.size);
                }
            };

            // Start recording with timeslice to ensure chunks are generated at regular intervals
            mediaRecorder.start(3000);
            document.getElementById('recordBtn').textContent = 'Stop Recording';
            var x = 1;

            const sendAudioChunks = async () => {
                if (audioChunks.length > 0) {
                    console.log('Sending chunks:', audioChunks.length);
                    const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { 'type': 'audio/wav' });
                    audioChunks = []; // Clear chunks after sending
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('audio_file', audioBlob, 'audio.wav');

                    try {
                        // Inside your try block within sendAudioChunks
                        const response = await fetch('/transcribe', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: formData,
                        });
                        if (!response.ok) {
                            // Log or handle non-200 responses here
                            console.error('Server responded with non-200 status:', response.status);
                        }

                        const data = await response.json();
                        console.log('Server response:', data);
                        document.getElementById('transcriptionContainer').textContent = data.transcription || 'Transcription failed or was empty.';


                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Failed to send audio chunks:', error);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('No chunks to send');
                }
            };

            clearInterval(sendInterval);
            sendInterval = setInterval(sendAudioChunks, 3000);

            mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
                clearInterval(sendInterval); // Clear the interval when stopping
                await sendAudioChunks(); // Send any remaining chunks
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error accessing media devices:', error);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media files don't work that way. To process a file, you need the beginning and the end.

If minor breaks in the audio are acceptable, you can restart the recording for every chunk. Start recording. Stop after N seconds. Store/Send it. Start recording. Repeat.

Else you need to change the api so it joins the chunks before transcribing. Api gets first N seconds, transcribes it, get the next chunks, appends it to the existing one, transcribes the last N seconds, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your `audioChunks = []; // Clear chunks after sending`. if you clear audio blobs here Blob size maybe small as waited and the backend side cannot process it for size problem. 
Send it without clear audioChunks.

And here if you want to send every last Blob(want to clear audioChunks) you should know event.data.size and check it with your min Blob size (ex: if Blob creates per 4 seconds it can be event.data.size>6000).
And here my code thats works perfect for me. I want to send audioBlobs that saves about 20-seconds (appends 4Blob) and after that clears:

```js
    recorder.mediaRecorder?.addEventListener(
            "dataavailable",
              async (event) => {
                if (event.data.size > 60000) {
                    recorder.audioBlobs.push(event.data);
                    console.log('Chunk received:', event.data.size);

                    const blob = new Blob(recorder.audioBlobs, { 'type': 'audio/wav; codecs=MS_PCM' });
                                      
                  if (recorder.socket?.readyState === 1) {
                    recorder.socket?.send(blob);
                    console.log(blob);
                    if (recorder.audioBlobs?.length >= 4){
                      recorder.audioBlobs = [];
                      recorder.mediaRecorder?.stop();
                      recorder.mediaRecorder?.start(4000);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            )
          
    recorder.mediaRecorder.start(4000);
```