# send audio blobs, receive python websocket streamer invalid input error

Tags: javascript, python

Send audio blobs from client every 4seconds with websocket. Here my eventListerner sending :

```js
recorder.mediaRecorder.addEventListener(
              "dataavailable",
              async (event) => {
                recorder.audioBlobs.push(event.data);

                const blob = new Blob(recorder.audioBlobs, {
                  type: "audio/wav; codecs=MS_PCM",
                });

                if (recorder.socket?.readyState === 1) {
                  recorder.socket.send(blob);
                }
              }
              );
              
              recorder.mediaRecorder.start(DELAY_TIME_MILLISECONDS);

            recorder.setStatus();

            recorder.visualize(stream);
          }
```

python receive from websocket.receive_bytes():

```py
while True:
                bytes_data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
                print("============received audio bytes")
                if bytes_data:
                    audio_bytes = BytesIO(bytes_data)
                    streamer = StreamReader(audio_bytes)
                    streamer.add_basic_audio_stream(frames_per_chunk=chunk_size, sample_rate=sample_rate, format='fltp')
                    stream_iterator = torch.concat([stream_arr[0] for stream_arr in streamer.stream()])
                    array = torch.Tensor.numpy(stream_iterator)
                    array = array[:, 0]
```

Here all works normal if append every chunk to prevs. But Blob size became big and real-time behind shedule,

I want to send only this chunk per 4seconds
it receives first blob, but at the second blob

error at the server side like below:
[image]
...
[image]

want send only last chunk from clint

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send recorder data in chunks to an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78165550/send-recorder-data-in-chunks-to-an-api)

Comment: Thanks for comment!` The error is like mine but I did Start/Stop | still this error...

Comment: I try `print(audio_bytes)` before `StreamReader()` this displays bytes comes from client, I think problem with server StreamReader. (StreamReader imported from torch.io)

Comment: Can you add more `mediaRecorder` code. Want to see how you stop it.

Comment: Please! You can see Here I edited the question upper.

Comment: I solve problem and here my answer for question like this :https://stackoverflow.com/a/78217563/17745835